# Beautiful soup encode to utf-8? Or no

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8

I am writing a program that web scrapes using beautiful soup and puts the values into a 5 column MySQL table. I plan to access these values with PHP through a web app or a mobile app which I will also write. I haven't decided yet what those apps will be. When I put these values into an array it became clear to me that they were Unicode values. My question is, do I need to encode to utf-8 using python before the values make it MySQL? Or should I wait until they're in MySQL? Do they need to be encoded at all? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautiful soup produces utf-8 by default. If you haven't changed that behavior it will be encoded in utf-8. Your DB drivers should be smart enough to put it into MySQL correctly.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit

What you need to be aware of is if your MySQL table is storing utf-8 data or otherwise. Usually you need to specify the type when creating tables or weird things can happen.